# How to get all field and immediately assign it?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

How i can get all the field and immediately assign it to some variable
I tried this

```
db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Users")
            .whereEqualTo("email", email)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                }
            });
```

I dont know if it the correct way and i dont know how to complete it.

Comment: You might want to start with the Cloud Firestore documentation to learn how to use the APIs.  There are lots of examples.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I already open it a few times by now, that that i got is from there, but i still cant do anything since i dont know how it worked

Answer (score 1):

I think it will easy for you to use Firestore.
With Firestore you can easily get the records with like "where" conditions.
Please check this example mentioned in the Firestore documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

```
db.collection("cities")
        .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I dont know how to use it. All i want is to get the value and put it in a variable. But i cant since i dont understand it.

Comment: You can check this link to quick start Firestore in your code:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart